# Get Value of Input Nested within Table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table where each row has two buttons and an input, nested within a `div`, in a cell. I must be able to filter out rows where the input is not an integer. The code worked until I added the 4 lines marked with asterisks (the two buttons).

```
<table id='myTable'>
{% for x in data %}
<tr>
<td style='max-width:175px;'>
  *<div style='display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;flex-wrap:nowrap;'>
    *<button name='plusminus' type="button" class="sub" style='display:none;'>-</button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control txtBox" style=max-width:90px; name="{{ x[2] }}" pattern="[0-9]{0,5}" title="Use only whole numbers. Eg 3 NOT 3.2" placeholder='Order...'>
    *<button name='plusminus' type="button" class="add" style='display:none;'>+</button>
  *</div>
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

The problem (I believe) lies in the '`firstElementChild`' and the '`firstChild`' below because when the asterisk lines above are removed the code works fine, indicating the problem is my function pointing to the wrong element.

```
<script>
function displayorderguide() {
   var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable'),
      rows = tbl.tBodies[0].children, l = rows.length, i,
      filter = function(cells) {
   var values = [
      parseInt(cells[0].firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/,/g,''),10),
      parseFloat(cells[{{parprofiles|length}}+2].firstElementChild.value.replace(/,/g,''))
                 ];
   if( Number.isInteger(+values[1]) ) return true;
                                      return false;
                              };
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
         if( !filter(rows[i].cells)) rows[i].style.display = "";
                   }
        }
</script>
```

My guess is I need to look at the first to grab the `div` and then the second to grab the input (where before I just needed the first to grab the input).

I tried replacing the '`firstElementChild`' with '`.children[0].children[1]`' but that does not seem to work.

So my question is, how does one parse multiple levels of html to get to that input now that it is nested within the `div`?

Comment: [`document.querySelectorAll('#myTable .textBox')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) might be a bit easier to deal with...

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('input.txtBox')` should work fine, given the HTML you've provided. Normally things like `firstElementChild`, `children` etc. are for when you don't have id's/classes to work with.

In your scenario, you might apply it like this:

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr');
document.querySelectorAll('input.txtBox').forEach((input, i) => {
    if (!Number.isInteger(Number(input.value))) rows[i].style.display = 'none';
});
```

In plain English:

1. Get all rows.
2. Get all inputs and iterate over them.
3. If the input's value is not an integer, apply `display="none";` to the associated row.